# Any example of usage of will_paginate wp_count_options in will paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

While i was reading the source code of will paginate i stumped upon a :wp_count_options setting in https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb#L150 I was trying to find usage examples for using this setting for example what is useful for ? Can someone point me to a good read about using this option with will_paginate gem ?

Comment: Have you seen this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713016/rails-page-call-on-model-also-calls-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of this answer

**[Rails .page call on model also calls count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713016/rails-page-call-on-model-also-calls-count)**

If what you are asking is not this, please let me know