# Rails .page call on model also calls count

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

Trying to do a simple `Model.all.page(1)`
But whenever .page is called, it creates a SQL COUNT call. (My actual code is more complex than above, but simplified for ease of reading.) Is there a way to prevent .page from calling a SQL count? I'm dealing with millions of products and this calls is making the page refresh take an extra 2 seconds to load. I already have my own custom count which is instant so I don't need this .page count.

Edit: Def not using .all. Bad example sorry.

Heres a really simple example that is basically my code in a nutshell:
`Product.limit(1).page(1)`
With my real code SQL produces: `(1495.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'products' LEFT OUTER JOIN...`

I have joins on the products table that I don't need to be counted, hence the fact I have my own count methods I want to use and don't need .page to produce it's own count.

Comment: Why are you using the `page` method directly?  Normally you'd use the `paginate` method.  And if you have another method you're providing that has the count for will_paginate to use, you can pass it in with the `:total_entries` option, e.g. `Model.paginate(:page => 1, :total_entries => 50)`

Comment: Pretty sure the COUNT query is not generated by the statement you think it is. Although it's related to the pagination stuff, it's likely a different statement. Something that is trying to figure out the total number of pages to create pagination for you. Have you 100% tracked the whole issue down to the #page call? If so then how?

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra, I can do both .paginate and pass in the options or .page and .per_page. Both give the pagination results I need however both result in a COUNT query

TanelSuurhans Well when I do Product or User or whatever Model.limit(1).page(1) and it 100% of the inserts a SQL COUNT call, I would say that's tracked down. I don't know any other way to track it down. If I do Model.page(1) it still returns the sql count along with the queried info, but goes through all of the products (which obviously I'm avoiding while debugging)

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing did you pass in the `:total_entries` option to the `.paginate` call?  If you don't pass in the :total_entries option, will_paginate will perform the count it needs.  :total_entries is an additional argument to :page and :per_page (you should have all of them otherwise you fall back on the defaults)

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra you are amazing. Please put the :total_entries as an answer and I'd love to accept it. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Sure thing... I updated the answer with the `total_entries` info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Model.all.page(1)` you are getting back an array instead of an ActiveRecord relation.

Try just calling `Model.page(1)` and you should get what you want...  If what you want is:

```
Model.page(1)

# results in SELECT "models".* FROM "models" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

**Edit:**
So the issue ended up being in the will_paginate gem as it was calling count on the query to know the total number of entries so it can get an accurate number of pages.  However will_paginate does provide an option to the `paginate` method which allows you to pass in a custom `total_entries` count which is useful if you have a massive table and don't care to get the precise number of pages for every record that matches the query.

You can pass in the option like so:

```
Model.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30, :total_entries => 100)
```

Comment: My DB has several million products so I have to add .limit(1) for testing. So when I do Product.limit(1).page(1) (essentially the same as your code), it gives a sql count:
`(57.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'products'`
Which I don't want/need

Comment: Hmm, I assume your `page` method comes from a pagination gem?  e.g. will_paginate or kaminari?

Comment: Yeah I use the gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate' which requires the basic 'will_paginate' gem.

Answer (score 1):

You are concerned about doing a COUNT query, yet you are selecting ALL records from your database by doing Model.all? Are you joking right now?
Also you need to provide code in order to get help. We cant read your mind, we cant make up what code you might have. Especially when you say "my actual code is more complex than above". Don't try to simplify issues or hide code that you THINK is irrelevant.

What does your code look like? What does your log look like, specifically query time and total page time (rendering and ActiveRecord split out). You need to give more information.

Comment: I've updated the question. The update has as much code as I can give, it's proprietary so can't give out the code. But the above is essentially the same. I just don't want .page to call a sql count

Comment: If it was Rails 4 it would not select all of the records.